# Do you know update site addresses for *latest* eclipse components?

Tags: eclipse, build, p2

I am looking for all addresses related to:

- 3.x eclipse itself (milestones and/or integration builds)
- 3.x other components (GEF, GMF, EMF, ...)

In the spirit of [answering my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-unofficial-faq#119658), I do have an answer for:

- [3.5 eclipse itself, with some details and **caveats**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138004/do-you-know-update-site-addresses-for-latest-eclipse-35-components#138013),
- [**3.6 Helios**, with the steps involved to follow the updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138004/do-you-know-update-site-addresses-for-latest-eclipse-3-5-components/1464210#1464210).

However, If you have further addresses, either for eclipse or other eclipse components, please publish them here.

Comment: added back the 'site' tag. With eclipse, 'update site' is relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **eclipse 3.6 Helios** (see [above for eclipse3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138004/do-you-know-update-site-addresses-for-latest-eclipse-3-5-components/138013#138013)), from ["**Catching up with Milestones and I-Builds**"](http://blog.eclipse-tips.com/2009/09/catching-up-with-milestones-and-i.html)

> The  **p2 repos** for Eclipse are not only for the stable releases, but also for the Milestones, I Builds and Nightly builds:
>   See [**Eclipse Project Updates Sites**](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Project_Update_Sites)

- [**Milestones**](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.6milestones): http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.6milestones
- [**I-Builds**](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.6-I-builds): http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.6-I-builds
- [**Nightly Builds**](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.6-N-builds): http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.6-N-builds

**Prakash G.R.** in his post advices:

> Go to your Preferences and add the required repo in your Available Software Site preferences (and disable all others, it will be slow to update).

[image]

> Also enable the automatic updates. You are done. Whenever there is a new Milestone (or an I-Build), then your Eclipse gets updated automatically to it and you don't have to worry about installing other required plug-ins

[image]

Answer (score 7):

**Update September 2009**: see also **[addresses for eclipse 3.6 Helios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138004/do-you-know-update-site-addresses-for-latest-eclipse-3-5-components/1464210#1464210)**

---

For eclipse itself, the [eclipse wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Project_Update_Sites)

- [3.5milestones](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.5milestones) http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.5milestones
- [3.5-I-builds](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.5-I-builds) http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.5-I-builds

However, the Milestone names are not there yet.
(For instance, the build number there is 20080807 is assumed to be 3.5M1)

The update site will be added as a location for builds in order to get published to automatically:
see bug [248509](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=248509)

Warning: the update process in itself might generate some freeze (see bug [234916](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=234916)) which might be solved by using a local http client (bug [220240](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=220240)).

Meaning you should first update your eclipse installation with the [ECF_Apache_Httpclient-Based_Provider update site](http://download.eclipse.org/technology/ecf/httpclientrepo) (http://download.eclipse.org/technology/ecf/httpclientrepo), then try the different update sites mentionned for eclipse components.

---

**Update May 2009**

The page "[**compare package**](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/compare-packages)" now provides all links to different released packages
(See links to the left of the page: Europa 3.3, Ganymede 3.4, Ganymede SR1, and Galileo 3.5Mx)

The [current available Galileo M6](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/galileo/m6) lists packages built with M6 release. That address will soon be not valid since [Galileo M7 has just been published](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/S-3.5M7-200904302300/eclipse-news-M7.html) (May, 2d 2009).
The new Galileo packages (M7) will then be at [this address](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/galileo/m7).

Comment: If other addresses should come up in this question, I would accept your answer instead of accepting mine ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about this one for Eclipse 3.5?
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo